# Determine the extreme values of the function $f$ with $f(x,y)=x^2y(4-x-y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, extreme-value-analysis

Determine the extreme values of the function $f$ with $f(x,y)=x^2y(4-x-y)$ for the points located inside and on the triangle delimited by the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x+y=6$.

Is this the function I'm going to need?

$$F\left(x,y,\lambda _1,\lambda _2,\lambda _3\:\right)=x²y\left(4-x-y\right)+\lambda _1x+\lambda _2y+\lambda _3\left(x+y-6\right)$$

Comment: No, find extreme values for $f(x,y)$ then verify if they are inside the triangle. Also, find extreme values on the boundary (i.e. when $x=0$, etc.)

Comment: Yes and no. As Vasili says, ignore the constraints to start with and find any critical points of f which are inside the triangle. Then use your F function to find if there are any critical points on the boundary.

Comment: I will try that out, but why can't I use this method?

Comment: If you are inside the triangle there is essentially no restriction on x, y apart from being in there. So find any critical points with no constraint, then check the points you find really are inside the triangle. That then leaves you with finding critical points on the boundery and your F comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange multipliers method allows for *optimization* under *equality* constraint ; our problem being an *equation solving* one and the constraint being an *inequation* one, this method is irrelevant.

So, we are back to the trivial solution of generating candidate solutions to the equation solving the check the constraint satisfaction. Being lazy, I'll use Sage for this.

```
# Setup
sage: y = var("y")
sage: f(x,y)=x^2*y*(4 - x - y) # Objective function whose extrema are sought
sage: Conds=[x>=0, y>=0, x+y<=6] # (Shortcut definition of the) domain of search.
```

All extremal points are poins where all the derivatives of the objective function are zero ; this gives us a first list of candidates :

```
sage: Args = f.args()
sage: C1 = solve([f(x, y).diff(u) for u in Args], Args) ; C1
[[x == 0, y == r4], [x == 4, y == 0], [x == 2, y == 1]]
```

But his condition is also true for saddle points ; extremal points are also points where the second derivatives of the objective function are either all (strictly) positive or all (strictly) negative ; hence a second list of candidates :

```
sage: C2 = [s for s in C1 if all([bool(d.subs(s)>0) for d in D]) or all([bool(d.subs(s)<0) for d in D]) ] ; C2
[[x == 2, y == 1]]
```

It remains to check that this solution is in the search domain :

```
sage: Sol = [s for s in C2 if all([c.subs(s) for c in Conds])] ; Sol
[[x == 2, y == 1]]
```

One notes that the only possible solution is on the boundary of the search domain.